# Python Chess Game, object has no attribute error

Tags: python, chess

I am currently making a chess game in python but keep coming up with an error that says "AttributeError: 'GameState' object has no attribute 'board'", however I'm pretty certain it should have this attribute . Any ideas on how to fix this?
This is the main file:

```
import pygame as p
from engine import * 

WIDTH = 512
HEIGHT = 512
DIMENSION = 8
SQSIZE = HEIGHT // DIMENSION
MAX_FPS = 15
IMAGES = {}

def LoadImages():
    pieces = ["wp","wN", "wR","wQ","wK", "bp","bN","bR","bB","bQ","bK"]
    
    for piece in pieces:
        IMAGES[piece] = p.transform.scale(p.image.load(r"C:\Users\Anderson\Documents\matthew's homework\KS5\Computer Science\Programming project\Programme\Prototype2\Chess\images/"  + piece +".png"),(SQSIZE, SQSIZE))


def main():
    p.init()
    screen = p.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    clock = p.time.Clock()
    screen.fill(p.Color("white"))
    gs = GameState()
    LoadImages()
    running= True
    while running:
        for e in p.event.get():
            if e.type == p.QUIT:
                running = False
        drawGameState(screen, gs)
        clock.tick(MAX_FPS)
        p.display.flip()

def drawGameState(screen,gs):
    drawBoard(screen)
    drawPieces(screen, gs.board)

def drawBoard(screen):
    colours = [p.Color("white"),p.Color("black")]
    for r in range(DIMENSION):
        for c in range(DIMENSION):
            colour = colours[((r+c)%2)]
            p.draw.rect(screen, colour, p.Rect(c*SQSIZE, r*SQSIZE,SQSIZE,SQSIZE))

def drawPieces(screen, board):
    for r in range(DIMENSION):
        for c in range(DIMENSION):
            piece = board [r][c]
            if piece != "--":
                screen.blit(IMAGES[piece],p.Rect(r*SQSIZE, c*SQSIZE,SQSIZE,SQSIZE))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the engine file that contains the game state class:

```
class GameState():
    def __innit__(self):
    
        self.board = [
            ["bR","bN","bB","bQ","bK","bB","bN","bR"],
            ["bP","bP","bP","bP","bP","bP","bP","bP"],
            ["--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--"],
            ["--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--"],
            ["--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--"],
            ["--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--"],
            ["wP","wP","wP","wP","wP","wP","wP","wP"],
            ["wR","wN","wB","wQ","wK","wB","wN","wR"]
        ]
    self.WhiteToMove = True
    self.movelog = []
```

Comment: You've written `__innit__` instead of `__init__` for the GameState class constructor.

Comment: On a side note - I hope the identation on the end of the `__init__` method is just innacurate due to copy/pasting here. If the file is actually indented like this, the 2 last assignments are not part of the method, and your code will fail.

Comment: Haha classic, "object has no attribute board, however I'm pretty certain it should have this attribute". How often have I thought I was better than the compiler, I feel you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Simple, you wrote `__innit__` instead of `__init__` in the class constructor which means it doesn't execute that function which leads to not creating the variable `self.board`